# knockout visible property data binding

Tags: html, data-binding, knockout.js

Not sure what's up with this, but the visible property does not seem to work using foreach.

This works (displays Testing 2 only):

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.firstName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.lastName"></td>
         <td>
        <div data-bind="visible: false">
           Testing 1
        </div>
         <div data-bind="visible: true">
           Testing 2
        </div>
         </td>
    </tr>
```

This doesn't work (displays both):
//boolean values = makeFalse is false and makeTrue is true

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.firstName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.lastName"></td>
         <td>
        <div data-bind="visible: $data.makeFalse">
           Testing 1
        </div>
         <div data-bind="visible: $data.makeTrue">
           Testing 2
        </div>
         </td>
    </tr>
```

Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: Can you reproduce in jsFiddle or provide a sample of your js code. If makeFalse and makeTrue are properties or observables that live on the items in your `people` array, then this should work.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer I could not reproduce the problem in jsFiddle. It works perfectly there. As for makeTrue and makeFalse they are called the same as first name and last name in arr but as bool E.g. { firstName: 'someFirstName', lastName: 'someSurname', makeFalse: false, makeTrue: true },

Comment: One thing to try is to put a cell like `<td><pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre></td>` in a row.  This will spit out what `$data` looks like.  You can verify that `makeFalse` and `makeTrue` are accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I remember getting stuck on something like this.  Try using ().

```
<div data-bind="visible: $data.makeFalse()"></div>
<div data-bind="visible: $data.makeTrue()"></div>
```